# Server Error in '/IIS' Application

Tags: asp.net

**Compilation Error**

**Description**: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message**: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PropertiesLayer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Check whether the requested `PropertiesLayer` is available.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code could not findout "PropertiesLayer" which you are refering in your code.

Where is PropertiesLayer defined ? Is it a seperate assembly ? Did you add a reference to that ? If not, add that. That would fix your problem.

Also make sure you are really using something inside that namespace, If you are not using,just remove the import /using statement. I have seen code where namespaces are refereed and not being used.